# PHP - Plugin or library for whitelisting certain HTML tags

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

I am running a blog which other visitors can post on. I want to allow certain HTML tags like headers, linebreaks or links. What is a good or best piece of plugin software I can use for this?

Additionally, is it best practise to save the raw data and then whitelist it when it is time for display in the blog. Or shall I whitelist the data before saving it to the database, so that it is saved clean?

Comment: why not use bbcode for messageboard instead of allowing html.
http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/misc.php?do=bbcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in function [`strip_tags`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) already has whitelist functionality that works quite nicely.

As for storage, it's a judgment call, but I recommend storing everything in its raw state and encoding for display only.  It's only a concern if you think you may accidentally forget to strip/encode on display.